# Issue with split string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split string in JavaScript, but I am not successful.

JavaScript code:

```
var string = TestApplication20   Application200;
var parts = str.match(/(\d+)(\D.+)/).slice(1);
var id = parts[0];
```

I need to retrieve 200 from the string, but I am getting 20 as the result.

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried `id = parts[1];`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str=  TestApplication20   Application200;
var str1=str.split(" ")[1];
var patt=/[0-9]+/g;
var pat_arra=new Array();
while (true) {
   var result=patt.exec(str);     //// or use var result=patt.exec(str1);
   if (result == null) break;
    pat_arra.push(result);

}
id=pat_arra[1]                    //// id=pat_arra[0] 

pat_arra[1] will have value 200   //// pat_arra[0] will have value 200
```

Comment: I have an another string like TestApplication Application 201.Then at that time i will face problem.Without array i need to retrieve the number.Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @shanuj Is **TestApplication** and  **Application** always seperated by a space ??? if yes then try this `var result=patt.exec(str.split(" ")[1])` and then `pat_arra[0]` will always have the last digit after the word **Application**.. edit the post as well...

Comment: If str = TestApplication100_101_102 Application200 then we will stuck with some errors i think.

Comment: @Kiran:  Not if you will use the `split(" ")` method, you will always work the logic on the **Application200** part....

Answer (score 0):

If you are always looking for a three-digit number, you could do this

```
var str = "TestApplication20   Application200";
var parts = str.match(/\d{3}/);
alert(parts);
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/PrFJv/

Comment: But what if `var str = "TestApplication201   Application203";`

Comment: @S.M.09, that was not a possibility put forth by the OP.  Both examples the OP gave... `TestApplication20   Application200` and `TestApplication Application 201` have one three-digit number only.